# How do I test the convergence/divergence of the following improper integral?

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

$$\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{(x-1)^{2/3}}$$

I also know of the result: if $lim_{x \to b}  (b- x)^r f(x)= A \not= \infty$, then $\int^b_af(x) dx$ converges. But this requires I take $-1$ out of the brackets, but then (-1)^{2/3} isn't real so should I say diverges?

Comment: The exponent in denominator is smaller than $1$. This is supposed to tell something, I bet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, change variables: $t=1-x$, then you get the integral (be sure to check the limits and signs, so you get that part)
$$
\int_0^1\frac{1}{t^{2/3}}\, dt.
$$
Can you work from here?

Comment: I get $3(-(-1)^{1/3})$. Diverges?

Comment: You can interpret $(x-1)^{2/3}$ as $((x-1)^2)^{1/3}$, and this equals $((1-x)^2)^{1/3}$. Now you don't have the problem with signs anymore, since $1-x$ is positive for $0<x<1$.

Comment: Checked with WolframAlpha, $-3 \sqrt[3]{-1}$ is correct.

Comment: Well, this depends on how one interprets $(x-1)^{2/3}$. Try to calculate the integral of $1/(1-x)^{2/3}$ from $0$ to $1$ in WolframAlpha, and I guess you will get $3$ as the result. If you calculate the integral in my reply, you will (hopefully) get the same.